# Angular - Display a field on UI based on other field ins empty or not

Tags: angularjs

I have two fields on screen UI. Lets field A and field B. 
I should be display field B only if Field A is not null.

is there any way I can do this validation on screen in html / js rather server side?

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-if to solve all of your conditional needs* https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

*Does not solve ***all*** conditional needs

Answer (score 0):

used ng-if which worked for me.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: I had a method in my controller which would set a field and i used that field in ng-if for hide and unhide